# Ant: Setup phpunit.xml

Tags: phpunit

In my application, I have the phpunit tests next to the source code. So in all maps next to let's say DoSometing.class.php I have a DoSomethingTest.class.php.

I want to configure phpunit.xml to test all these *Test.class.php files.

How do I do that in phpunit.xml?

I  have something like this at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit 
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="true"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="true"
    stopOnFailure="true"
    syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="My Test Suite">
            <directory>./*Test.class.php</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <groups />
    <filter />
    <logging />
    <listeners />
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a similar structure, only our test files end with the extension .TEST, or .QTEST, .JTEST based on the testing framework since we have JavaScript and other embedded code as well that needs testing.  As such, we use the suffix option on the directory node as shown below.

```
<phpunit>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Your Test Suite Name">
            <directory suffix=".test">.</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

For the PHP Unit tests (*.TEST) we use the following PHPUNIT.xml (this is edited for size)

```
<!-- PHPUnit Core Settings -->
<phpunit backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="PeriScope-Bootstrap.php"
             ...

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="ICAP User Interface Library">
            <directory suffix=".test">lib/.</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Enterprise Scale Manager">
            <directory suffix=".test">ESM/.</directory>
        </testsuite>
        ...
    </testsuites>

<!-- Add files not covered with tests into Code Coverage Analysis -->
    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".class">lib/.</directory>
            <directory suffix=".fn">lib/.</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/.</directory>
            ...

            <exclude>
                <directory>ExternalLibraries</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        ...
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Does this also scan all the subdirectories?

Comment: Yes, we have more directories underneath that get processed as well.